# Overload power with correctly in c++?

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading, xor

In c++ I implemented an `integer` class and I overloaded `operator ^` to be the power  function.

```
integer integer::operator^ (const integer& rhs){
       return integer(pow(this->.i, rhs.i));
}
```

This is working correctly for two operands.

```
integer i1, i2, i3 ;   
 i4 = i1 ^ i2 ^ i3;
```

The value of `i4` is wrong mathematically because associativity required right-to-left. How can I solve this problem? How do I change associativity?

**I got reasonable answers and I learn:**

```
-We can't change  associativity or priority of an operator.   
-Good is Not to overload operators to do something conceptually different to 
 the built-in versions  
-Even compiler can't support; it hard to implement!
```

Comment: -1: Show us some code of real value. I'm not psychic (nobody is), so I cannot see what your definition for `operator^` is.

Comment: Even if you could change the associativity (which you can't), the precedence would be confusing; `a * b^c` would be parsed as `(a*b)^c`. It's usually best not to overload operators to do something conceptually different to the built-in versions.

Comment: @user1705796 Yeah you really don't wanna do that. Having '^' as power will confuse anyone used to '^' meaning XOR (that is, every single C++ dev ever). Also, it's not wrong "mathematically". Left/Right associativity is not a mathematical property (although associativity is - ^ is not associative by the way, (a^b)^c != a^(b^c)), it's just a convention.

Comment: @user1705796: Seriously? Do you think "but Y -ve" is something you can type in public and expect people to put up with you? If you can't spare the five seconds to type out an English sentence, why should we spend five minutes to think about your question?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot change the associativity or priority of an operator in C++ by overloading it. These rules are hardwired into the language syntax.

The C++ standard says (§13.5.6, emphasis mine):

> An operator function shall either be a non-static member function or be a non-member function and have
>   at least one parameter whose type is a class, a reference to a class, an enumeration, or a reference to an
>   enumeration. **It is not possible to change the precedence, grouping, or number of operands of operators.**
>   The meaning of the operators =, (unary) &, and , (comma), predeﬁned for each type, can be changed [...]

Not only is the `^` operator left-associative, but [it also has a very low precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). The correct precedence for a power operator should be higher than the multiplication (so priority 4 or better on this table), but it has priority 10--this means that even additions and subtractions are evaluated before it. `1 + 2 ^ 3 * 4` will be parsed as `(1 + 2) ^ (3 * 4)`, while a mathematically correct power operator should parse as `1 + (2 ^ 3) * 4`.

If the associativity or priority of an operator could be modified, a huge, huge syntactical mess would ensue. My humble opinion is that you should not try to overload the `^` operator to use it as a power operator. I would rather make a `power` method on the class.

Comment: there is no ambiguous association or priority in that case.

Comment: @user1705796, that's because associativity does not kick in until you chain operators. No matter if an operator is left- or right-associative, it makes no difference if you use it just once. Problems arise when you use it more than once in a row, for instance `a ^ b ^ c`. With a left-associative `^` operator, this becomes `(a ^ b) ^ c`. With a right-associative operator, it becomes `a ^ (b ^ c)`. This is a problem for a power operator because it is non-commutative: you cannot reorder operands and get the same result (as you would with the addition or multiplication operators, for instance).

Comment: You could always use the class in polish prefix notation, this would solve your issue with operations.

Comment: @zneak Thank for answer I almost understood the assignment only about  how to overload operator but I could n't enhance language. Thanks a lot for your great answer!

Comment: @Need4Sleep: Sorry I could n't understood What you said :( but thanks!...Can you add one more comment.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation read up on this notation, the computer usually transforms your equations into this notation and uses stack to perform operations.

Comment: @user1705796, if this answer solved your problem, consider clicking the checkmark under its score. It marks it as "accepted" and tells other people that this is the information you were looking for.